# There is no vkreal module in pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I wanted to install the vkreal module in Pycharm, but I was faced with the fact that it was not in the interpreter and could not be found through pip. What could be the problem or what other ways are there to install the module?

Comment: If you are talking about [this vkreal](https://github.com/abrzv/vkreal) then it's not a package on PyPi so you can't install it with pip. You need to clone the repo and add it to your project manually